# Conditional slicing on a Pandas dataframe containing a column of lists. (Possible?)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

Let's take this dataframe that has a column of lists:

```
In: df = pd.DataFrame([['one', [1,2,3,4]], 
                       ['two', [1,3]], 
                       ['three', [0,2,4]]],
                      columns=['id', 'items'])      
Out:
      id         items
0    one  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1    two        [1, 3]
2  three     [0, 2, 4]
```

If I want to filter by 'id' I would simply do:

```
In : df[df['id']=='two']
Out: 
     id   items
 1  two  [1, 3]
```

However, I cant seem to find a way to do something similar for the items in 'items'. I would like to find something of the sort:

```
In: df[df['items'].contains(2)] 
or 
In: df[(2 in df['items'])] 

Out:
       id         items
 1    one  [1, 2, 3, 4]
 2  three     [0, 2, 4]
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Indeed, the answer from the associated question works, but only if instead of a column of lists, you convert to a column of arrays.